# Expanding a Pi notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

How to expand/rewrite the product $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x-a_i)$ into a sigma notation $\sum\limits_{j=0}^n b_jx^j$?

I am trying to extract all coefficients ($b_j$ in the above expression).
In my attempts I see that $b_j$ should contain $n-j$ of the $a_i$ s and is sort of the sum over all products of them somehow.

Intuitively and after working with smaller examples, I know how it should look like but cannot give a closed form expression for $b_j$.

Comment: Hint: lookup [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). The product form is a monic polynomial with roots $a_i$, the sum form is the same polynomial after expansion of the products, with coefficients $b_j$.

Comment: Note that for $x=a_\ell$, $\prod_{i=1}^n (a_\ell-a_i)=0=\sum_{j=0}^n b_ja_\ell$.

Comment: Yes, I tried to expand using the fact that if we regard the product as a equation it has $a_i$ as its roots. This gives me a system of $n$ equations in $b_j$ and it's still hard to give a closed form expression for each $b_j$?

Comment: Did you notice the pattern ?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n (x-a_i)=
    \sum_{j=0}^n 
    (-1)^j \left( 
        \sum_{1 \le k_1 \lt \cdots \lt k_j \le n} \ \prod_{m=1}^j a_{k_m} 
    \right) 
    x^j
$$

The enclosed parenthesis requested terms the [Elementary Symmetric Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) terms $b_j=(-1)^j e_j(a_1,...a_n)$, closely related to the [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), as very well indicated in the question comments.

Comment: Is “$\sum_{1 \le k_1 \lt \cdots \lt k_j \le n}$” the same as “$\sum_{\{1,k_1,\cdots,k_j,n\}}$ given that $1 \le k_1 \lt \cdots \lt k_j \le n$”? And am I correct when I presume that the elements of $\{1,k_1,\cdots,k_j,n\}$ will be substituted in place of $k_m$?

Comment: The enclosed sum operator should be equivalent to the nested sum: $$\sum_{k_j=1}^n \sum_{k_{j-1}=1}^{k_j} \cdots \sum_{k_1=1}^{k_2}$$. That notation was taken from wikipedia. The indexes values should not be repeated in a single product (we should not have a $a_i^2$), The indexes $k_m$ are thus defined inside the product operator, and can be used for obtain for example $a_{k_1}a_{k_j}$ if necessary.

Comment: Okay, wonderful